# Within WSL session, ssh to external Linux box

Tags: ssh, password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to ssh without password to Linux server from WSL in Win10. I setup private and public keys as usual, copy over public key to Linux server, and add it to authorized keys.

ssh *still* requires password.

What is the procedure for using keys when **within** WSL, if *possible*?

Comment: AFAIK there is no special procedure (I just tried it and it worked for me). What does "as usual" mean, exactly - and how did you copy the public key to the server (using `ssh-copy-id` or by some other means)? Does it jump straight to requiring a password, or does it try the key and fail? Have you done any lower level debugging such as adding `-v` / `-vv` / `-vvv` to your ssh invocation to see details of the authentication negotiation?

Comment: In WSL, I used `ssh-keygen` to create a keypair, then `ssh-copy-id user@host` to install it, and then had keypair auth working with no issue.  Check the permissions of your private key maybe?

Comment: I was using dsa not rsa. Using steeldriver comment above, I found that dsa public was not being used. Not certain why rsa key worked without issue.

Comment: @paulj iirc DSA for public key authentication has been deprecated/removed by OpenSSH - see for example [Why OpenSSH deprecated DSA keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys)

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way:**
Generate the keypair from WSL terminal as per normal

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

Then use [ssh-copy-id](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id) command from WSL to remote Linux server

```
$ ssh-copy-id user@remote-server
```

You will be asked for a password. Once the password is accepted, key exchange will happen in the background.  Then logout from remote Linux server and try to log back in. No password will be required this time. That's all you need